# will java ExecutorService shutDown method can ensure all submit task will finally submitted

Tags: java, executorservice

As the [ExecutorService document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) explains `The shutdown() method will allow previously submitted tasks to execute before terminating`. So in my initial understand, all submitted task will still be finally completed when we kill thread through **ctrl+c**.  But it seemed the actually result is not.

The generation of the executorService as below:

```
CORE_POOL_SIZE = 1
return new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, numConsumers,
                                  KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(),
                                  consumerThreadFactory);
```

And in my task, I will log some information the task code sample like this:

```
log.info("before come into sleep.....")
try {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.warn(" exception during sleep.....{}", request.getExecutionId());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 log.info("after come into sleep...")
```

I submit several task and then terminal thread through **control+c**, and the result is that only the log **before come into sleep** is print.

So I dont know whether my understand is correct that **shutDown can ensure all submitted task be completed finally**. I also google some similar question but find there are no explicit answer.

Comment: Ctrl-C doesn't do anything special to work smoothly with Java.

Comment: can I use the command: `kill pid`?

Comment: Like Ctrl-C, that will instantly kill the Java process and all its threads without giving them a chance to finish.

Comment: I will very appreciate if you have command to recommend .

Comment: I do not have a command to recommend.

Comment: You might have some luck calling the executor’s awaitTermination method in a [shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).  Of course, some types of process termination cannot be intercepted by the JVM or by any program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Control+c kills entire JVM

Pressing Control+c on the console terminates the entire Java process running your threads. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C#In_command-line_environments).

You are interrupting the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). This is *not* a graceful way to interact with your Java app.

So, no, you should not expect your executor service to continue running submitted tasks. You killed it.

The JVM is generally not designed to be manipulated in the console after launch. After launch, the only two ways I know of for interacting with the JVM is:

- The user-interface of your app, [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) or [console-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application).
- [Java Management Extensions (JMX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions)

You said:

> we kill thread through ctrl+c

No, ctrl+c does not specifically kill a thread. It kills your entire JVM.

### `awaitTermination`

After calling `ExecutorService#shutdown`, if you want your code to block and wait until all submitted tasks are done, call `ExecutorService#awaitTermination`. Specify a certain amount of time to wait before throwing an exception if tasks are still running.

This waiting for termination is [shown in the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and has been discussed in many other Questions and Answers on Stack Overflow, some authored by me. So search to learn more.

Comment: So how should I terminal java service then can ensure all tasks can be completed? Actually, I just want to confirm whether the ShutDown method can ensure all submitted task be completed finally.

Comment: And I also have another question, whether the running submitted tasks is equals with running submitted  tasK? As you know I use a queue to store task if there are no free thread, then I dont know whether these tasks that are in queue when terminal service will also be ensured to be completed?

Comment: @nailfei  Regarding confirmation of shutdown, see my edits.  As for queueing, that is the job of an executor service. You should not be doing any queueing yourself. **Just submit all your tasks to the executor service.** The executor service sees to their execution as threads become available and/or creates threads as needed depending on the type of executor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is clear from the docs for `ExecutorService` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) that it doesn't wait for the tasks to complete. We have `awaitTermination` for this purpose.

```
This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.
```

A clear example of how to achieve this is available in `Usage Example` section of this documentation as well.

**Why is awaitTermination important during graceful shutdown?**
Using `shutdown()` is like informing your intention to stop all the threads managed by the `ExecutorService`. There is no blocking involved here. Your main thread shall resume execution and continue executing subsequent code after `shutdown()`. While handling graceful shutdown of a JVM (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html), a separate thread will be called expecting it to complete its task and when it does complete, JVM shuts down. If you need to wait for the tasks to complete, **block** the shutdown hook thread using `awaitTermination()`.

Comment: Thanks for you response. In my understand the **shutDown** method is enough to ensure all submitted tasks will be completed finally,  here explain why we need awaitTermination: https://coderanch.com/t/618942/java/awaitTermination

Comment: Using `shutdown()` is like informing your intention to stop all the threads managed by the `ExecutorService`. There is no blocking involved here. Your main thread shall resume execution and continue executing subsequent code after `shutdown()`. While handling graceful shutdown of a JVM (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html), a separate thread will be called expecting it to complete its task and when it does complete, JVM shuts down. If you need to wait for the tasks to complete, block the shutdown hook thread using `awaitTermination()`.